# mp4 play on Google TV emulator, but won't play on Google TV device

Tags: android, google-tv

I use the following code to play mp4 video:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url, "video/mp4");
ctx.startActivity(i);
```

It works fine on phones & tablets, as well as Google TV emulator, but throws ActivityNotFoundException on Google TV device.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tried to play an MP4 video using the above code snippet ,I am getting "No application can handle this action" message. Looks like there is no default application which can play the video. ActivityNotFoundException occur normally when you give the wrong media type.

Comment: Does it really mean that Google TV devices do not have a default app for playing video??

Comment: Will report this to engineering team and get back to you.FYI ,you can also file  google tv related bugs here at http://code.google.com/p/googletv-issues/

Comment: Reply from Engineering team: Currently GoogleTV doesn't have any built-in applications that can handle these intents. Accepted as a Feature Request.

Comment: Do you know if it possible to play mp4 video by implementing MediaPlayer class in the app?

Comment: MP4 is supported video format for Google TV and it should work with MediaPlayer class.You can try out the MediaPlayer Apidemos http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/index.html

Comment: Here is a basic media player with simple play controls: https://github.com/commonsguy/vidtry